# How can I match everything in a string until the second occurrence of a delimiter with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to refine a `preg_match_all` by finding the second occurrence of a period then a space:

```
<?php

$str = "East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots. Waters a moderate chop.  Slight chance of showers.";

preg_match_all ('/(^)((.|\n)+?)(\.\s{2})/',$str, $matches);

$dataarray=$matches[2];
foreach ($dataarray as $value)
{ echo $value; }
?>
```

But it does not work: the `{2}` occurrence is incorrect.

I have to use `preg_match_all` because I am scraping dynamic HTML.

I want to capture this from the string:

```
East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach

```
$str = "East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots. Waters a moderate chop.  Slight chance of showers.";


$sentences = preg_split('/\.\s/', $str);

$firstTwoSentences = $sentences[0] . '. ' . $sentences[1] . '.';


echo $firstTwoSentences; // East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get all periods then a space and only use some of the results?

```
preg_match_all('!\. !', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0][1]; // second match
```

I'm not sure what exactly you want to capture from this however. Your question is a little vague.

Now if you want to capture everything up to and including the second period (followed by a space) try:

```
preg_match_all('!^((?:.*?\. ){2})!s', $str, $matches);
```

It uses a non-greedy wildcard match and `DOTALL` so `.` matches newlines.

If you don't want to capture the last space, you can do that too:

```
preg_match_all('!^((?:.*?\.(?= )){2})!s', $str, $matches);
```

Also you may want to allow the string termination to count, which means either:

```
preg_match_all('!^((?:.*?\.(?: |\z)){2})!s', $str, $matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('!^((?:.*?\.(?= |\z)){2})!s', $str, $matches);
```

Lastly, since you're after one match and want the first one, you could just as easily use `preg_match()` rather than `preg_match_all()` for this.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I am scraping a dynamic list, but this looks like it will work:

(^)((.|\n)+?)((?:.*?\. ){2})

Can you translate this last part for me?

((?:.*?\. ){2})

2nd occurrence of ... huh?

Thx.

Comment: @Steve `(?:...)` is a *non-capturing group* meaning it won't create a separate entry in the `$matches` array. It otherwise acts as a capturing group in terms of precedence, etc. `.*?` is a *non-greedy* wildcard match. Normally wildcard matches in regexes grab as many characters as possible. Non-greedy matches grab as few as possible.

Comment: Well, my simplified example didn't get me the second occurrence of ". ", so I'll show you what I am doing: View the source of: weather.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/… I am running: preg_match_all ('/(#800000">)((.|\n)+?)((?:.*?\.\s){2})/',$content,$forecast); $dataarray=$forecast[2]; foreach ($dataarray as $value) { echo $value; } to try and get only: Tonight South Winds 10 To 14 Knots. Bay Waters A Light Chop. Friday Southwest Winds 10 To 15 Knots. Bay Waters A Light Chop. Still no joy. Any ideas??? Thanks so much for the help...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<?php
$str = "East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots. Waters a moderate chop.  Slight chance of showers.";
if(preg_match_all ('/(.*?\. .*?\. )/',$str, $matches))
    $dataarrray = $matches[1];
var_dump($dataarrray);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(40) "East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots. "
}
```

Also if you want to capture just one occurrence, why are you using `preg_match_all` ? `preg_match` should suffice.

Comment: Any reason why you have 3 r's in array? :P

Comment: @alex: Its an optimization hint to the PHP interpreter ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think (.\s{2}) means what you think it means. As it stands, it will match ".  " (a period followed by two spaces), not the second occurence of ". "

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I knew the {2} was wrong. I thought there might be a quick fix, so I simplified my question. The real example is scraping the source of:

http://weather.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/fmtbltn.pl?file=forecasts/marine/coastal/am/amz630.txt

and doing a preg_match_all to end up with only:

TODAY
SOUTHEAST WINDS 7 TO 12 KNOTS BECOMING 10 TO 13 KNOTS. BAY
WATERS A MODERATE CHOP.

TONIGHT
SOUTHEAST WINDS 8 TO 12 KNOTS BECOMING SOUTH 5 TO
10 KNOTS. BAY WATERS A LIGHT CHOP.


etc., for each day. 

Is there a way to do the 2nd occurrence of ". " in the way it is structured now?

Answer (score 0):

no need regex. think simple

```
$str = "East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots. Waters a moderate chop.  Slight chance of showers.";
$s = explode(". ",$str);
$s = implode(". ",array_slice($s,0,2)) ;
print_r($s);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to capture this from the string: East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots.

I have two suggestions:

1) Simply Explode the string at ".  " (double space) and just print the result.

```
$arr = explode(".  ",$str);
echo $arr[0] . ".";
// Output: East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots.
```

2) Use Explode and Strpos which is more performance-friendly than Preg_match_all.

```
foreach( explode(".",$str) as $key=>$val) {
    echo (strpos($val,"knots")>0) ? trim($val) . ". " : "";
}
// Output: East Winds 20 knots. Gusts to 25 knots.
```